# Is it atomic operation to read/write elements in a array?

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

I have multiple threads accessing the elements from one shared array marked as final (I'll never try to assign another array to it). Do I need to synchronize anything? Can I assume that the read/write to an element is atomic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The writes are atomic unless the array is of type long or double. However, the atomic property won't help you because the writes won't be guaranteed to be **visible** to other threads.

If the array is of reference type, the problem is even worse because other threads may see your objects torn apart: some fields visible, some not.

To safely share a random-access collection of elements, you'll need either a `synchronizedList` wrapper around a plain `ArrayList`, or a lock-free `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

If you are OK with the fixed size of an array (and it would seem so), then also look into `AtomicReferenceArray` since it allows atomic compare-and-set and get-and-set operations, which may take you a step further in implementing what you need without the need for locks.

Comment: It's an array of String. Is it the same as int/long/double? As the string is immutable.

Comment: String is a special case in that it is safely publishable via a data race. However, the visibility issues for the references themselves will not go away.

Comment: `AtomicReferenceArray` might be more appropriate here than a `List`.

Comment: How about declaring array as volatile ?

Comment: @mac that just makes the variable holding the reference to the array volatile. It has no effect on the array itself.

Comment: If an array is declared volatile, and if a new element is added to array, other threads may or may not see that change. Do you mean that ?

Comment: @mac Yes, approximately that. Writes to array elements are plain writes.

Comment: Is this visibility issue a concern when holding the **entire** array reference?  What if a Supplier<Object> that's scoped to the array context, supplies me with a specified index in the array? new ThreadObject(() -> array[0]).start(); Would that Supplier suffer from the same visibility issue?

Answer (score 0):

since you have multiple threads that can read and write the elements of the vector, it can happen that when a thread reads, another writes the same cell. put a synchronized block.
pseudo code example:

```
    public void get(index i){
        synchronized(..){
           //your code
        }
    }
```